# call php function inside jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$.each(data, function (rowNumber, rowData) {

    var row = $('<tr>');

    row.append($('<td>', {
        'html': '*HERE*'
    }));

        $('#js-lobby-table').append(row);
    });

    state = data;
};
```

am I need to call the rowData and the PHP function in the *HERE* I don't know how to combine this
PHP function is getName
I have tried this unsuccessfully:
'html': 'rowData['UID']'
sample of data is `UID`

Comment: What's wrong with `<?php echo yourFunction();?>`

Comment: Though you should watch for quoting issues and instead do `'html': <?php echo json_encode(yourFunction());?>`

Comment: the problem is 
PHP function with argument
olso the rowData

Comment: no sample data?

Comment: @Wils
thanks for the comment I just added to the description the sample data `UID`